# Swift - View doesn't update enumerated id's and gives 'Index out of range'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a view with two sections.
The idea is to track exercises, and what you have "planned" appears down, and what you actually have done appears on top.
I have done that as two lists, ´comittedSets´ and ´uncomittedSets´.
The repetitions and weight fields in the ´uncomittedSets´ also need to be changeable (hence the ´uncomittedRepsandValues´)

So, this is my model class:

```
import Foundation

class CurrentWorkoutModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var activeWorkout = Elevatu_WorkoutPlan()
    
    @Published var hasActiveWorkout : Bool = false
    
    @Published var isPreviewingWorkout : Bool = false;
    
    @Published var setsComitted : [Elevatu_WorkoutLogSet] = []
    
    @Published var setsUncomitted : [Elevatu_WorkoutLogSet] = []
    
    // corresponds 1-1 to setsUncomitted text for TextFields because Swift is
    // pain in the ass on text values
    // is in order [reps, weights]
    @Published var uncomittedRepsAndWeight : [[String]] = []
    
    // Needs previewWorkout to be called before
    // (activeWorkout sat to something)
    func startWorkout(){
        
        self.hasActiveWorkout = true
        setsUncomitted.removeAll()
        uncomittedRepsAndWeight.removeAll()
        
        for plannedSet in self.activeWorkout.exerciseList{
            var uncomittedSet = Elevatu_WorkoutLogSet()
            uncomittedSet.exercise = plannedSet.exercise
            uncomittedSet.reps = plannedSet.reps
            
            setsUncomitted.append(uncomittedSet)
            uncomittedRepsAndWeight.append([String(plannedSet.reps), ""])
            
        }
    }
    
    func previewWorkout(workout: Elevatu_WorkoutPlan?){
        var unwrappedWorkout = workout ?? Elevatu_WorkoutPlan()
        
        if (workout == nil){
            unwrappedWorkout.name = "Freestyle"
            unwrappedWorkout.notes = "You can freely pick any exercise in any order."
        }
        
        self.isPreviewingWorkout = true
        self.activeWorkout = unwrappedWorkout
        
    }
    
    func logSetButtonDisabled(id: Int) -> Bool{
        let editedFields = uncomittedRepsAndWeight[id]
        return (editedFields[0].isEmpty || editedFields[1].isEmpty);
    }
    
    func commitSet(id: Int){
        print("Trying to commit set with id " + String(id))
        
        let set = setsUncomitted[id]
        
        print("Found set: " + set.exercise.name + " , " + set.reps.formatted() + " x " + set.weight.formatted() + " kg")
        
        uncomittedRepsAndWeight.remove(at: id)
        setsUncomitted.remove(at: id)
        
        setsComitted.append(set)
    }
    
    func updateRepsAndWeightValues(id: Int){
        print("Trying to unwrap text at " + String(id))
        
        let uncomittedValues = uncomittedRepsAndWeight[id]
        
        print("Got values: " + uncomittedValues[0] + " x " + uncomittedValues[1] + " kg")
        
        // reps
        if let uncomittedReps = Int32(uncomittedValues[0]){
            setsUncomitted[id].reps = uncomittedReps;
        }
        
        // weight
        if let uncomittedWeight = Float(uncomittedValues[1]){
            setsUncomitted[id].weight = uncomittedWeight;
        }
    }
    
}
```

And my View:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ActiveWorkoutView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model : CurrentWorkoutModel;
    
    @FocusState var textInputsFocused;
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{ // todo - make exercises clickable
            List{
                Section(header: Text("Logged exercises")){
                    HStack{
                        Text("Exercise").frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading).fontWeight(.heavy)
                        Text("Reps").frame(width: 75).fontWeight(.heavy)
                        Text("Weight").frame(width: 75).fontWeight(.heavy)
                    }
                    ForEach(model.setsComitted, id: \.self){ workoutSet in
                        HStack{
                            Text(workoutSet.exercise.name)
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                            Text(workoutSet.reps.formatted())
                                .frame(width: 75)
                            Text(workoutSet.weight.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(1))) + " kg")
                                .frame(width: 75)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Upcoming exercises")){
                    ForEach(Array(model.setsUncomitted.enumerated()), id: \.element){ i, workoutSet in
                        HStack{
                            Text(workoutSet.exercise.name)
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                            TextField(
                                "Reps",
                                text: $model.uncomittedRepsAndWeight[i][0],
                                onEditingChanged: {
                                    if !($0){ // stopped editing
                                        model.updateRepsAndWeightValues(id: i)
                                    }
                                }).keyboardType(.numberPad).focused($textInputsFocused)
                            TextField(
                                "Weight",
                                  text:$model.uncomittedRepsAndWeight[i][1],
                                  onEditingChanged: {
                                      if !($0){ // stopped editing
                                          model.updateRepsAndWeightValues(id: i)
                                      }
                                  }).keyboardType(.decimalPad).focused($textInputsFocused)
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                textInputsFocused = false
                                model.updateRepsAndWeightValues(id: i)
                                model.commitSet(id: i)
                                }){
                                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                }.disabled(model.logSetButtonDisabled(id: i))
                            
                        }.foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
        }.navigationTitle("Current workout")
    }
}

struct ActiveWorkoutView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        
        var model = CurrentWorkoutModel()

        ActiveWorkoutView(model: model)
    }
}
```

When you click on the button, it's supposed to move the data from `uncomittedSets` to `comittedSets`, and remove the corresponding value in `uncomittedRepsAndWeight`.

It seems to work for the first one-two `uncomittedSets` I click on, but when there's just two remaining, I get 'Index out of bounds error'.
My guess is the index i in the `ForEach` is not updated in the functions to be called, and the function calls on the old id's (and not the removed ones). Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: restructure your code to **not** use indices like you do. As you have found out, it is a recipe for disaster. eg `uncomittedValues[0]` or `$model.uncomittedRepsAndWeight[i][1]` etc...

Comment: Why are you using semicolons? It appears as though you placed them there at random. You should remove the indexes at least. Accessing an array by index anywhere outside a loop can lead to a lot of bugs.

Comment: You should watch Demystify SwiftUI